# how to swap two items in multiple lists

Tags: c#, list, swap, grasshopper

Let's say that I have this data:

List:

1. ListOfPoints = a
2. ListOfPoints = b
3. ListOfPoints = c
4. ListOfPoints = d

Now what I'm trying to do is: swap two points inside every list (a, b, c, d), unfortunately it's not working.

I tried the following code:

```
List<List<Point3d>> currentGeneration = handoverPopulation.ToList();
foreach(List<Point3d> generation in currentGeneration)
{
  int index1;
  int index2;
  Random r = new Random();
  index1 = r.Next(0, generation.Count);
  index2 = r.Next(0, generation.Count);

  if(index1 != index2)
  {
    Point3d cache = generation[index1];
    generation[index1] = generation[index2];
    generation[index2] = cache;
  }
}
```

How do I swap two points in more than one list simultaneously or why does my approach not work?

Here is a picture of the Lists before and after swapping: 
[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Side note: `generation` is a better name than `Var` for the local variable. You may want to read the naming conventions for c#.

Comment: Thats true, I should change the name for the local variable .  When I'm finished with the fundamental programm, then I will still change few things at the end though.

Comment: What is the problem you are experiencing with your code?

Comment: I don't know why but this code is not swapping any Points in any lists (a,b,c,d). The lists are still the same before and after swapping. Let me post a Picture. @symmetricsaurus

Answer (score 1):

You should not create a new `Random` instance for each iteration in the list. That way it is reseeded for iteration. Since the seed is timer based it will likely be seeded with the same value each time and thus give the same values.

The below code works for me:

```
Random r = new Random();
foreach (List<Point3d> generation in currentGeneration)
{
    int index1;
    int index2;
    index1 = r.Next(0, generation.Count);
    index2 = r.Next(0, generation.Count);

    if (index1 != index2)
    {
        Point3d cache = generation[index1];
        generation[index1] = generation[index2];
        generation[index2] = cache;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have not tried this in Grasshopper, only in a C# console app. Maybe the issue is somewhere else in your app? Can you put a breakpoint in your code and see that it runs at all? Otherwise try to figure out what values you get from Random.Next().

Comment: Hey I found out the reason now. It is actually working but the code would swap points in both lists. I had a initial list I was refering to with this code, so therefore it was not possible for me to see the difference before swapping and after swapping. To change this the only thing I had to do is: clone the initial list first, so that you can compare them!  @symmetricsaurus

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're dealing with reference types when you try and swap the points around. Creating 'new' points (instead of referencing existing points) fixed this. Tested in Grasshopper C#.

```
int index1;
int index2;
Random r = new Random();
index1 = r.Next(0, generation.Count);
index2 = r.Next(0, generation.Count);

if(index1 != index2)
{
  Point3d cache = new Point3d(generation[index1]);
  generation[index1] = new Point3d(generation[index2]);
  generation[index2] = cache;
}
```

Comment: Hey @James R, thank you. That is a good idea as well, but I just cloned the list and then let the swapping code run. It is working :)

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help.

I found out why it would not work or why would I not see any difference. 
It was because there was the initial list where I wanted to swap points. To achieve that, I just copied the hole list, and let the swapping code run. However the program would swap in both list and therefore it was not possible for me to see the difference.

After all troubles :) the only thing I had to do is, to clone the initial list. So I tried this:

```
public static List<List<Point3d>> createGenerations(List<List<Point3d>> cGP, List<double> cGF, int genSize, Point3d startPoint)
{
 List<List<Point3d>> currentGeneration = new List<List<Point3d>>(cGP.Count);
 cGP.ForEach((item) => {currentGeneration.Add(new List<Point3d>(item));});
}
```

Now I can swap anything I want in 'currentGeneration' while seeing the difference before and after swapping.